# Marionette ItemView event handling conflict with Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, marionette

I have a Composite view creating a table, with the childView collection displaying each row. At the end of each row is a Bootstrap based button dropdown. 
Clicking on the row will open a modal (working), but the event is still fired when clicking on the button dropdown, so the modal shows AND the dropdown shows underneath.

How do I prevent the clicks on the button from propagating down to the row click event, without preventing the Bootstrap hooks from also getting cut?

The standard method for handling these types of special click events (in my research and book reading), uses `e.stopPropagation()` on the jquery event that comes back, to prevent the event from going further, but this blocks the Bootstrap dropdown open event from triggering.

If I still call stopPropagation() when the buttongroup is clicked, then use the event object's currentTarget object and toggle the class manually, I can get the dropdown to open without conflict, but since the close button triggers are 4 layers down, I would have brute force & call .parent() 4x times to toggle the class, and that doesn't sound very sustainable or portable.

How can I have a row-click action AND open and close the dropdown using Bootstrap's built-in toggle?

**ItemView**

```
Show.Result = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName:"tr",
    template: "#row-template",
    events:{
        "click .js-delete-result": "editRow",
        "click .js-edit-result": "deleteRow",
        "click div.btn-group button": "openSettings"
        "click": "rowClicked",
    },
    editRow: function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert("you trying to delete bro?!")},
    deleteRow: function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert("you trying to edit bro?!")},
    openSettings: function(e){
            //e.stopPropagation()
            //$(e.currentTarget).parent().toggleClass('open')
            //e.currentTarget.button('toggle');
        },
    rowClicked:function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        this.trigger("show:result",this)
    },
}
```

**Template**

```
<script id="row-template">
    <td class="vert-align"><%= value %></td>
    <td class="vert-align"><%= notes %></td>
    <td class="vert-align">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"/>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="js-edit-result">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="js-delete-result"> Delete <i class= "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
</script>
```

**Random Idea:** Maybe I'm thinking of the problem the wrong way, and should instead find a better CSS / jQuery selector that would cover all but the button-group; Is there a 'not' selector with CSS?

**EDIT:**
I tried changing the `"click": "rowClicked",` generic click handler to use the 'not' css selector; `"click :not(div.btn-group *)": "rowClicked"`, but it did not have any effect; it still opens the model when the button is clicked. AFter more research, I realize that my not selector is not formatted / used correctly, but that might be largly because I'm trying to use it in a way it's not made for.

**EDIT 2:**
I was able to finally prevent the propagation (sort of), but in the process discovered that TWO separate clicks were being generated. <strike>I don't know why.</strike> It's because the event propagation is never stopped, and bubbles down to the root HTML element, in this case the TR.

Changing the generic click function to check what the target of the click is, and whether it's ancestors contain the `.btn-group` class, every time you click, but only on the button itself; if you click on just the row then it only fires once.

How can I prevent this propagation / set event listeners on the correct items?

```
    rowClicked:function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("I get called twice?!")
        if($(e.target).parents('.btn-group').length > 0){
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            e.stopPropagation()
            this.trigger("show:result",this)
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ton of googling and testing my code, I think this may be the best approach for now. It does not really address the core of my question, but since a generic click event handler was inserting itself before bootstrap could get to it, changing the focus of the click to something more specific seems to have done the trick.

Thanks to `@Pawan` and `@squall3d` for some pointers in this direction, but I am still looking for an answer on how to better propagate / setup / control event listeners to prevent conflicts with other libraries in the future.

However, to get it working for now, I changed the generic click to `"click td": "rowClicked"`. `td` is almost the base layer, but specific enough so it won't interfere with the button events. I no longer needed the button click handler, (we want bootstrap to do it), so that was removed: <strike>`"click div.btn-group button": "openSettings"`</strike>

```
Show.Result = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName:"tr",
    template: "#row-template",
    events:{
        "click .js-delete-result": "editRow",
        "click .js-edit-result": "deleteRow",
        "click td": "rowClicked",
    },
    editRow: function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert("you trying to delete bro?!")},
    deleteRow: function(e){e.stopPropagation();alert("you trying to edit bro?!")},
    rowClicked:function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        this.trigger("show:result",this)
    },
}
```

It is worth noting that I *did* add additional code to the rowClicked function, to prevent opening the modal if the button dropdown was being shown and you clicked on a row accidently when clicking outside the dropdown to close it. I found this to be a better user experience.

```
    rowClicked:function(e){
        if($("#edit-btn").hasClass("open")){
            //also do nothing - the dropdown is open
        }
        else{
            e.stopPropagation()
            e.preventDefault()
            this.trigger("show:result",this)
        }
    }
```

and added an id to the btn-group for jquery selection

```
<div class="btn-group" id="edit-btn">
```

this works because Bootstrap adds an `.open` css class to trigger showing the dropdown html.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, have not tested. What id you stop propagation at the button's parent? e.g. `click div.btn-group` ? It shouldn't interfere with default bootstrap behaviour yet it stops it from bubbling to the row itself.

Comment: Didn't work. Without e.stopPropagation(), it propagates to the generic click (rowClicked), and _with_ the stopPropagation, it still manages to muddle with the bootstrap listeners. (but does stop the propagation). Unsure why stopPropagation at the DIV level would affect the button's bootstrap listener, but it appears to do so.

Comment: worth trying adding it to a parent higher up then, and listen on that e.g. `.actions-wrapper` in

    <td class="vert-align actions-wrapper">
        <div class="btn-group">
        ...

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
  rowClicked:function(e){
    if($(e.currentTarget).is('td')){ //or e.target will also do
        this.trigger("show:result",this);
    }
},
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, and is just a rehash of the rowClicked function I already added at the end; I'm more interested in learning why marionette overrides bootstrap's listeners. Thanks though!